# Add excel-like element list in HTML table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

I would like to realise a table with a specific functionnality on header, in fact I would like to do like in Excel spreadsheet, a header capable of displaying a list of any elements in the column...

I looked over datatable for Jquery and others plugin, but no one could realize what I want. Does anyone know if such functionnality already exists ? And if not, what would be the easiest to implement it..?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you are looking for but doesnt this example of data tables achieve what you need ?

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: Oh...My bad... I should looked deeper on datatable website... That's nearly what I'm looking for... Thanks for the really quick answer !